# SocialCommentWebPart: Where can we see the comments?

Tags: content-rating, social-note

I'm working with a colleague who wants to add both `SocialCommentWebPart` and `AverageRatingFieldControl` to a page template, so that our customers can rate and leave comments on certain pages of our publishing site. Adding the web parts is fine and they works, but the concern is how to view the all the ratings and/or comments without having to go to each individual page to view them. The solution we're looking for would be SharePoint UI based rather than scripted, and in a central location ideally for all sites within the site collection or at least at a site level.

So, my two questions are:

- Are rating and comments added to a SharePoint list somewhere that we can view?
- Is there an ootb page that shows all the comments?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rating and comments are managed by User profile service application and the data is stored in Social Tagging database independent of content database of your site collection.

You can see the comments by per user and/or url along with date range by going to Central Admin > Manage Service Applications > User Profile Service (name could be different) and selecting “Manage Social Tags and Notes”

If this does not meet your need, you may have to write your own application page and use SharePoint APIs. Look for relevant classes here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.socialdata.aspx

Comment: Many thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I found the right place in Central Admin. It's unfortunate that the page only allows specific user or exact URL searching, rather than "show all" or "show for this site" options, so your link to the API may end up being more useful. That said, my question was answered, for which I thank you :)